# RuntimeException: Could not launch activity when running instrumented tests on AWS device farm

Tags: android, android-fragments, aws-device-farm

I have some instrumentation tests for Android. When I run them in Android Studio (both emulated and on a device) they are fine, however when I run them on an AWS device farm a couple of them fail with the error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not launch activity android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.startActivitySync(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:371)

They appear to be the ones testing the fragments, but that may be misleading.  I'm new to Android but I think they are both running the same apk?

The test:

```
package uk.co.stuff

import android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView
import android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches
import android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed
import android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText
import android.support.test.filters.LargeTest
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
import com.android21buttons.fragmenttestrule.FragmentTestRule
import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.not
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import uk.co.stuff.MyFragment
import uk.co.stuff.models.Driver
import uk.co.stuff.utils.Constants
import uk.co.stuff.utils.DatabaseUtil

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class ProfileFragmentShould {

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val fragmentTestRule = 
       FragmentTestRule(FragmentActivity::class.java, MyFragment::class.java, true, true)

    @Test
    fun not_show_payment_details() {
        DatabaseUtil.setUser(Driver().apply { type = Constants.INDEPENDENT_DRIVER })

        fragmentTestRule.launchFragment(MyFragment())

        val paymentDetails = 
          fragmentTestRule.activity.getString(R.string.payment_details)
          onView(withText(paymentDetails)).check(matches(not(isDisplayed())))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong apk.  I needed to use the debug and androidTest versions generated when building and assembleAndroidTest